# Localization in iOS framework

Tags: ios, localization, frameworks

I want to add localisation to my framework, some texts for errors description.

How I can do it? Standard approach with `Localizable.strings` and `NSLocalizedString` does not work.

I read about bundles, but I don't know how to add bundle with localisation correctly.

Some one can help?

Comment: do you mean localize the error log info?

Comment: Its not important

Comment: if localize something, it should in iPhone sand-box, do your framework in sand-box?

Comment: What do you mean?..

Comment: do you mean localize a text file in yourself's framework? but where the framework is, in the iOS application, if not in sand box library, can not write data.

Answer (score -2):

use Bundle(for: yourClassName.self)

Comment: Do you have a snippet which localizes a string using your `Bundle` suggestion?